# Bash - working with ASCII so slow

Tags: performance, bash, printf

I have a bash script that takes 2 arguments - a character and integer. I want to print chars in aplhabet starting with that character of length of that integer (modulo the alphabet)

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# != 2 ]] && echo Exactly 2 argument needed && exit 1
[[ "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]$ ]] || { echo Enter only one char; exit 2; }
[[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo Enter integer; exit 3; }

letter="$1"
cnt="$2"
letter=`printf "%d" \'$letter`;
z=`printf "%d" \'z`
a=`printf "%d" \'a`
[[ "$1" =~ ^[[:upper:]]$ ]] && { ((letter+=32)); }           # make lower

while [[ "$cnt" -gt 0 ]]; do

  printf \\$(printf "%03o" "$letter")
  ((letter++))
  [[ "$letter" -gt $z  ]] && letter=$a                       # alphabet modulo
  ((cnt--))
done   
echo ""
```

This script works perfectly fine, but it's too slow. I have to call 2x n (value of int) the printf program.

My question is if there is something like `enable printf` working solution to boost up the speed of printf execution or some solution not using printf at all.

I need to use bash and I just want to know how to handle ASCII the fastest possible way. I'm scripting on cygwin atm, so there could be some speed fails related to it.

This script is just an illustration of problem, I don't want some "increase stdout flush buffer size" solutions. Thanks :)

Comment: `bash` is designed for gluing together other programs, not bulk data processing. If you want to process data the fastest way possible, pick a different language.

Comment: @chepner is right. This would be much quicker in a language like perl or python (available on cygwin as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $# != 2 ]] && echo Exactly 2 argument needed && exit 1
[[ "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]$ ]] || { echo Enter only one char; exit 2; }
[[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo Enter integer; exit 3; }

alpha=`echo {a..z}|sed 's/ //g'`
letter="$1"
cnt="$2"
letter=$(expr `printf "%d - %d + 1" \'$letter \'a`;)

[[ "$1" =~ ^[[:upper:]]$ ]] && { ((letter+=32)); }           # make lower

echo -n `echo $alpha |tail -c +$letter |head -c $cnt`
((cnt=cnt-26))
while [[ "$cnt" -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo -n `echo $alpha |head -c $cnt`
    ((cnt=cnt-26))
done
echo ""
```

This program uses brace expansion to expand `a..z` into the list of characters and then displays this string cut to size using head and tail. It could be even more optimized, but that is an exercise for you.

Performance comparison(`<1>` is code in question, `<2>` is code in this answer):
* Startup section has 4 commands in `<2>` as compared to 3 in `<1>`.
* `<2>` runs 4 commands (echo (x2), head, tail) per 26 characters, as compared to 1 command  per character in `<1>`.
* `<2>` has one arithmetic operation per 26 characters while `<1>` has 2 arithmetic operations per character.

```
samveen@precise:/tmp$ time bash 1.sh a 1000
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl

real    0m2.065s
user    0m0.244s
sys     0m0.552s
samveen@precise:/tmp$ time bash 2.sh a 1000
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl

real    0m0.285s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.060s
```

Further reading: `man bash`

Comment: I like this idea. Marked as answer.